# Android NDK return byte array of bitmap's pixels

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-ndk

I have to do some processing of a bitmap, and I'm trying to use NDK to return a byte array to java by locking Bitmap pixels. After processing in java is done, I (*finally*) call another NDK function to unlock bitmap's pixels.

I've tryied a few things but no one has worked:

- returning to java the void* returned by lock pixels operation
  (casting it as jbyteArray), didn't work (sigsegv).
- Using a ByteBuffer also didnt work because its read only (I need to manipulate it from java).
- All other approaches that seem to work, will create a copy of the array... I'm trying to avoid this in order to reduce memory
  consumption.

Comment: If you search around on stackoverflow you can find some answers.  See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_sharing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved this by manipulating the array entirely inside native code. All Java code that used the byte[] has been moved to JNI.

According to my research, I think there is no way to manipulate the byte array of a Bitmap directly from Java. Of course you can manipulate a copy, but I dindt find any way to work directly with the native bitmap's data.

If someone finds a way, I would like to know it.

Regards!